# ubuntu, MySQL change datadir

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, datadirectory

I just installed Mysql 5.7 on new ubuntu distribution 16.
I am trying to move Mysql Datadir into a specific Disk. I followed then

But when trying to start mysql it fails

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since mer. 2016-08-17 21:08:09 CEST; 10s ago
  Process: 4735 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

août 17 21:08:09 getesa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
août 17 21:08:09 getesa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
août 17 21:08:09 getesa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
août 17 21:08:09 getesa systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
août 17 21:08:09 getesa systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
août 17 21:08:09 getesa systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Please help me.

Comment: so go look at the mysql logs to see why it failed. until you know what the failure cause is, anything else you do is simply randomly poking at things in the dark.

Comment: Where can I look for the error?

Comment: it'll be specified in mysql's config file. probably in /var/log somewhere

Comment: Actually it seems that the mysql service is not even trying to start.
And no, No error is shown in the /var/log/mysql/error.log file since I tried this move.
Thanks Marc.

Comment: maybe you have a same issue with me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036434/mysql-5-7-change-datadir/48501908#48501908 hope helpful