# MySQL 5.7 change datadir

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL 5.7 and CentOS 7.2.

At first, my datadir configuration in my.cnf is /var/lib/mysql

Now I want to change datadir.

I hava try two ways:

First, I copy all files and directories in /var/lib/mysql to /home/data, and run `chown -R mysql:mysql /home/data`. But when I run `systemctl start mysqld`, I get error message:

```
2016-12-08T16:33:38.206780Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2016-12-08T16:33:38.206806Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2016-12-08T16:33:38.206817Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2016-12-08T16:33:38.807398Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-12-08T16:33:38.807421Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-12-08T16:33:38.807429Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2016-12-08T16:33:38.807436Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Second, I move /var/lib/mysql to /home  and run `ln -s /home/mysql mysql` in /var/lib directory. When I run `systemctl start mysqld`, I get error message:

```
2016-12-08T16:48:28.958136Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2016-12-08T16:48:28.958165Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2016-12-08T16:48:28.958174Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: os_file_get_status() failed on './ibdata1'. Can't determine file permissions
2016-12-08T16:48:28.958184Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2016-12-08T16:48:29.558751Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-12-08T16:48:29.558792Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-12-08T16:48:29.558806Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2016-12-08T16:48:29.558817Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: I had this problem in windows. Once I deleted the log file the service started properly. ibdata1 will be the log file, if you have backup delete it and try start service again

Comment: @Rajesh I had tried to delete all `ib_logfile`. But it doesn't work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ibear where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is about subdir permission
and you should edit this file `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`

`/data/ r,
/data/** rwk,`

do not forgot, and you should find same command at centos, like this

`sudo service apparmor reload`

about this problem at ubuntu sys, and see link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/758898/mysql-wont-start-after-changing-the-datadir-14-04-mysql-5-7/795710#795710

happy day, baddy